# Import dashboard from kibana 7.5.1 to kibana 7.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to import a dashboard from kibana 7.5.1(prod) to kibana 7.4.1 (test). If I cannot do that I'll need to create a new dashboard in kibana (test) from scratch. However, in kibana's doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-saved-objects.html, it notices "Exported saved objects are not backwards compatible and cannot be imported into an older version of Kibana. ".

When I called import api in console to import the dashboard from 7.5.1 to the 7.4.1 version kibana, it shows mapper_parsing_exception error. Is there any way to modify the dashboard.ndjson file to import it to an older version kibana?

```
POST /api/saved_objects/_import
{
  "file" : "C:\Users\dashboards-kibana\EKC-Dashboard-Prod.ndjson"
}

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unrecognized character escape 'U' (code 85)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@33da7471; line: 2, column: 17]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to rebuild it, as the docs say you cannot export newer versions to older ones

Comment: Thanks, I modified the ndjson file multiple times and even transfer it to json format still not works.